# install4j: How to replace header banner

Tags: install4j

How to replace in Install4J 7.0.8 installer header image installer_header.png to custom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the installer (for changing all screens) or a single screen, change the "Style" property from "Default" to "Standard", select the "Customize title bar" property and change the "Image File" property.

In both cases, the above properties override a property in the "Standard" style. To see the original property, go to Installer->Styles, edit the "Standard header" and look at the "Image File" property of the "Vertical group" form component. It is configured in the "Allow external overriding" property of the form component, so that it can be overridden in installer applications, screens and screen groups.